# General Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given smooth $f$. What is the solution $g$ of

$$ \lambda g''(x)=f(x)g(x) $$

where $\lambda>0$?

or more generally, given also $h$:

$$ \lambda g''(x)=f(x)g(x)-h(x)g'(x) $$

Comment: you're right. since questions cannot be deleted here, I'll change it to another one I have.

Comment: @Troy I believe this is considered a bad form. You can delete a question by clicking `delete` under it.

Comment: somehow i dont have delete here like in other stackexchange, i also cannot vote here.. they have some bug

Comment: @Troy: your user is listed as "unregistered" here, and doesn't appear to be linked to other stackexchange sites except for StackOverflow. As an unregistered user, you cannot vote or delete. But I wonder if you have another SE account with different log-in credentials that somehow got split from this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general method for solving such equations. For example, the solutions of the innocent-looking equation 
$$g''(x) = xg(x) \tag{1}$$ 
are Airy functions. What are Airy functions, one might ask? Well, they are defined as solutions of (1).